# Expected number of trials which picks all colors in jar

Tags: probability, statistics

(I'm not good at english.. consider it please..)

If there is a jar which has N number of balls in all different colors.

with replacement, what is the expected number of trials that all the balls are picked?

Comment: Ref: [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).  Is there any question about it in particular  ?

Comment: wow, thank you Graham Kemp. I will read Ref and ask more if i can't understand for something. thank you again!!